# LyX: cannot convert file. Error occured while running

Tags: errors, lyx

I have been using LyX for about a year now and I have not encountered this problem. This happened two days ago and up to now I have still not been able to address this issue. I want to visualize my LyX document in `pdf`. I have uninstalled and installed LyX and yet the problem still persist. I keep on receiving this message:

```
LyX cannot convert file
Error occurred while running python-tt...
```

I am using LyX 2.0 on Window 7. could anyone help me out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: LyX depends on a LaTeX installation. Which (La)TeX distribution are you using? On the command prompt you can test whether `pdflatex` is working by something like `pdftex '\empty Hello world!\bye'` which should produce the file `texput.pdf`. For more details, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, which of the available LyX bundles did you install? If you have a separate version of MiKTeX installed, you might want to try to [download](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/bin/2.0.5.1/LyX-2.0.5.1-Bundle-5.exe) the bundled version of LyX and reinstalling.

Secondly, did you install another tool that depends on Python or update the Python version installed on your PC? Possibly, this might cause some interference with the Python libraries LyX is using. This might also explain why the problem is persistent although you reinstalled LyX.